# The correct usage for 'on' and 'at'

Tags: grammar

Question is simple and direct and is very specific to usage in a particular scenario.

The person, xyz, who works 'at'/'on' the post of a typist does a good job.

I am having a healthy debate with multiple people in this regard and the opinion is divided.

Please refrain from saying "both usages are correct" unless you can strictly back the same with source.

Step by step constructive interpretation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. You work *at* a place, *at* or *on* a task, but *in* a post. However, it would be much more idiomatic to say *who works as a typist* or *who holds the post of typist.*

Comment: I have upvoted but will add that *"who works **at/on [or in]** the post of a typist"* is so unidiomatic that I would mark it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A relevant definition of *post* is "place when on duty," 1590s, from Middle French poste "place where one is stationed," also, "station for post horses" (16c.), from Italian posto "post, station," from Vulgar Latin *postum, from Latin positum, neuter past participle of ponere "to place, to put" (see position (n.)). Earliest sense in English was military; meaning "job, position" is attested 1690s.

[Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/post)

There is therefore strong connotation of place to *post*, which strongly justifies “working *at* a post” but not *on* it.

The use of *on* might be more weakly justified by the implication that someone working at a typing post would necessarily be working on tasks to do with typing.

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as an answer as it only addresses the word "post" rather than the preposition. "In the post of" is relatively common. (https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/work-at-in-the-post-of-translator.3064848/)

Comment: @Greybeard I hoped that I had dealt with the choice of preposition by reference to the connotations of *post*. I agree with your comment about *in* but that is to broaden the discussion beyond the question that was asked.